# Checking that the date and time in the list of web elements goes from high to low. Selenium, Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

There is a list of date and time, for example:

```
06.04.2023 15:20,
06.04.2023 11:50,
03.04.2023 22:47,
29.03.2023 21:06,
29.03.2023 23:07,
27.03.2023 19:26.
```

In this case, the list may change, but in fact the list always goes in descending order.
I need to make sure that the date and time go from the largest to the smallest (thus the appropriate assert is needed).

I run through the web elements through the `for()` loop, and using the `getText()` method, I get the values the elements.

```
@FindBy(css = "locator")
private List<WebElement> allDate;

Array List <String> justList = new ArrayList<>();
for(WebElement element : allDate) {
    justList.add(element.getText());
}
```

But there is a problem in the formation of the assertion itself, that in fact the periods of time are arranged in order from largest to smallest.

Please, tell me about this issue, can anyone have a practical solution.

Comment: You need to parse the dates to get in each case a simple number (say seconds since some base date). Then it's trivial to determine if they're ordered.  For that, simply assert in the loop that the N'th entry is not less than the N-1'th entry, with due attention to the 'first' pass through the loop.  You don't even need to create the list.

Comment: @ArfurNarf Parsing is correct, but using numbers is not. Parse into `LocalDateTime` objects as shown in the answer. They can be compared using `isBefore()` or `isAfter()`, which is even clearer.

Comment: Do you need to take summer time (DST) and other time anomalies into account? When the clocks are turned back in fall, some funny order of the times may occur that could still agree with descending order of clock readings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I've done this in the past, I've found that it's easiest to convert the datetime string to an actual DateTime java object, copy the list, sort the copy, and then use an Assert to compare the unsorted and sorted lists. In this case I'm using [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html). If the original list is sorted correctly, it will match the sorted list exactly.

```
@FindBy(css = "locator")
private List<WebElement> allDateTimes;

// loop through each element, get text, and store it
List<String> dateTimeStrings = new ArrayList<>();
allDateTimes.forEach(e -> dateTimeStrings.add(e.getText()));

// declare a formatter that defines the expected datetime format
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm", Locale.ENGLISH);

// loop through each datetime String, convert to LocalDateTime, and store it
List<LocalDateTime> dateTimes = new ArrayList<>();
dateTimeStrings.forEach(dateTimeString -> dateTimes.add(LocalDateTime.parse(dateTimeString, formatter)));

// copy the LocalDateTime List and sort it
List<LocalDateTime> dateTimesSorted = new ArrayList<LocalDateTime>(dateTimes);
Collections.sort(dateTimesSorted, Collections.reverseOrder());

// Use TestNG assert to compare Lists
Assert.assertEquals(dateTimes, dateTimesSorted, "Verify that the datetimes on the page are sorted in descending order");
```